# How to implement Multiparty Audio Conferencing system without using peer-to-peer connection in HTML5?

Tags: html, audio, webrtc, html5-audio, video-conferencing

Currently I am using WebRTC for video broadcasting(Single video source multiple client) to streaming a video using [RTCMultiConnection.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast)

I also want to implement Multiparty Audio Conferencing  system(every one can talk and every one can listen from all members of conference).

We can implement it using WebRTC(using [RTCMultiConnection.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast)) but it will not be efficient due to peer-to-peer communication (**In Mesh topology**). It will need more bandwidth and CPU processing.

Please anybody can suggest me any other option to implement **Multiparty Audio Conferencing** system without peer-to-peer communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- Asterisk:
  http://www.asterisk.org/get-started/applications/conference
- McuWeb:
  http://www.medooze.com/products/mcu/open-source-installation.aspx
- FreeSwitch:
  https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/FreeSWITCH+1.6+Video